# What role does Radagast the Brown play in "The Hobbit"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Having heard that Sylvester McCoy is slated to play the role of Radagast the Brown in the upcoming film adaptations of "The Hobbit", I am wondering what role this character actually plays in those events?

Comment: Of note, Radaghast sent the eagles to rescue Gandalf in *The Two Towers*, yet he didn't appear in that movie and wasn't even mentioned.  Perhaps this is to compensate :P

Comment: Radagast talks with birds to scout information from a wide idea and relays information to Saruman before he realizes Saruman's treachery.  This is very likely how Saruman finds out about the ring turning up in the Shire at about the same time as Gandalf does.  I don't think this is mentioned in the Hobbit though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like Legolas, Radagast doesn't actually appear in *The Hobbit*, although he is mentioned briefly by Gandalf and is a friend of Beorn who does appear. The upcoming movies are based- somewhat loosely perhaps- on both *The Hobbit* and the intervening period before the opening of *The Lord of the Rings*, so Radagast may play some role at Dol Guldur or other wizardy events which are not explicitly covered in *The Hobbit*.

Answer (score 6):

Radagast is a member of the White Council.

During Bilbo's adventures Gandalf leaves Thorin's party at the border of Mirkwood as he has been summoned to a meeting of this Council. This meeting decides to, in alliance with the elves of Lothlórien, go to war to drive The Necromancer (Sauron) from his stronghold in Dol Goldur.

Answer (score 0):

He does what the Istari were sent to do, in scouting and information gathering, etc. Whereas Saruman sits on the sidelines sniping.